# how to stop page getting loaded from browser history

Tags: header

I am using

```
$(function(){ 

   $("#header").load("header.html"
   $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
 });
```

to load header and footer in all the pages of website. But ive a scriptfor menu bar in header.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("very slow");
    });
});

function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {
        alert("sfdfsd");
        document.getElementById('panel').style.display = 'none';
        };
</script>
```

----------**************--------------

well the problem is when i load another page the header is not getting completely reloaded. rather than that its getting loaded from history and my menu bar style will be changed to value "block".

Someone pls help me loading header completely on each page.